# how to change a file originalname in Multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload files to Google Cloud Storage bucket and MongoDB, which is actually working but changing the file name isn't cause I can't and I have looked it up online but can't see a similar code to mine so how do I change the file `originalname` adding a `date.now()` to it.

MY CODE

```
const multer = Multer({
    storage: Multer.memoryStorage(),
    limits: {
      fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, // no larger than 5mb, you can change as needed.
    },
  
  });
  

//CREATE FEED

Router.post('/', multer.array('files'), authoriazation, async (req, res) => {

    const { txt, Feedtype } = req.body
    const text = htmlToText(txt, {
        wordwrap: 130
      });
     
    // uploading multiple image
  
       
        const creteFeed = await new Feed({
            feedby: req.user,
            feedTxt: text,
            deleted: 0,
            feedReaction: 0,
            feedComment: 0,
            feedShare: 0,
            feedType: Feedtype,
        })
        const newFeed = await creteFeed.save()
  if (req.files.length > 0) {
        for (newfile of req.files) {
            const blob = bucket.file(newfile.originalname);
            const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();
            if (newFeed) {
                const FeedMed = await new FeedMedia({
                    feed_id: newFeed._id,
                    feedby: req.user,
                    feedMedia_type: newfile.mimetype,
                    feedMedia_name: newfile.originalname,
                    category: 'feed',
                    url: `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${newfile.originalname}`,
                    deleted: 0
                })
                const newFeedMed = await FeedMed.save()

                }

            blobStream.on('finish', async() => { 
            });

            blobStream.end(newfile.buffer);

        }

    }
    res.json('success')
})
```

Comment: Does the bucket file name have `originalName` as its name? Do you only want to append the date to the filename apart from `originalName`?

Comment: Why can't you store `originalname` in DB only anfd generate an unique file name to store in GCS?

Comment: yes i want to append date to the filename apart from the originalname then save it to the database

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add **Date.now()** to **file.originalname** in ***SERVER SIDE*** you can do so:

`const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, 'www/img/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname); // <-- CHANGE HERE
  }
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post("/upload", upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send();
})`

and make a Fetch post so:

```
const file = document.querySelector("input#file").files[0];
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', file); // <-- DO NOT CHANGE HERE

fetch('/upload', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
});
```

But, if you want to add **Date.now()** to **file.originalname** in ***CLIENT SIDE*** you can do so:

`const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, 'www/img/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.originalname); // <-- DO NOT CHANGE HERE
  }
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post("/upload", upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send();
})`

and make a Fetch post so:

`const file = document.querySelector("input#file").files[0];
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', file, Date.now() + '_' + file.name); // <-- CHANGE HERE

fetch('/upload', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
});`

In this case, the **file.originalname** will change in **SERVER SIDE** after the post.

Comment: Thanks a lot, gilbriatore. Can you plae add a "+" in the following line (before "file.name"): formData.append('file', file, Date.now() + '_' + file.name); // <-- CHANGE HERE

Comment: Certainly! Done!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Multer.memoryStorage` which doesn't support filename options because you don't have a file name when storing files in memory.

https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/288

You can use `Multer.diskStorage` instead.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#diskstorage

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})
 
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```